# Could you please assist me with PHP 5.3 and MySQL 5.5 stored procedures and mysqli library + persistent connection

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli, persistent-connection

Helo,

I have a stored procedure that has 7 IN parameters and 3 OUT parameters.
I need to pass 7 parameters IN from PHP, execute the query with procedure, and retrieve the 3 OUT parameters.

I am using mysqli with persistent connection mode enabled. (For load considerations)
What is the most efficient way to execute the query and get results?

I need something that doesn't affect other concurrently running PHP scripts, and that cleans the result itself, and that is straightforward.

This is what my application is (simplified) (not a working example, just how i wish it was)

```
$inParam1 = 'wer';
$inParam2 = 'fewf';
$inParam3 = 'dsf';
$inParam4 = 'vccv';
$inParam5 = '34t3'; 
$inParam6 = 'ter';
$inParam7 = 'ert';
$query = "CALL my_procedure('$inParam1', '$inParam2', '$inParam3', '$inParam4', '$inParam5', '$inParam6', '$inParam7', @outParam8, @outParam9, @outParam10); SELECT @outParam8, @outParam9, @outParam10;";
$result = $mysql_query($query);
list($outParam1, $outParam2, $outParam3) = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $outParam1; // String param #1 that my procedure returned as an OUT variable
echo $outParam2; // String param #2 that my procedure returned as an OUT variable
echo $outParam3; // String param #3 that my procedure returned as an OUT variable
```

If somebody could show how this code could look in reality, please please would be great!

I am obviously using mysqli with proper connection, and such, but the examples I have found in internet are really confusing and seem to be inefficient, I am also worried if it will conflict with other clients, because it works like "nextResult" and other some strange functions.

Many thanks!

PHP 5.3, MySQL 5.5

Comment: Do you have any example of your code?

Comment: just posted what it looks like in my head

Comment: but i don't have any working example because i can't understand how to accomplish it, if you could help suggest the most optimal and efficient way to do it, even if it is with bind_variables or so, it would be great

Comment: This is how my query looks when I just execute it in mysql admin and pretend that I am program: `CALL my_procedure('test', 'test2', 'test4', 'bla', 'ewer', 'ABC', '123', @outParam8, @outParam9, @outParam10); SELECT @outParam8, @outParam9, @outParam10; why can't I replicate that in PHP`

Answer (score 0):

Try looking here. As im not overly familiar with this. :)

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx

You need to create a query first. This query will then be stored in the database as a callable procedure. Then later using whatever language you can call the procedure.

```
DELIMITER //  
    CREATE PROCEDURE GetUserByCountry(IN countryName VARCHAR(255))  
        BEGIN 
            SELECT name, email   
            FROM users  
            WHERE country = countryName;  
        END //  
DELIMITER ;
```

Then calling it.

```
CALL GetUserByCountry('mexico')
```

Returns all users names and emails who live in mexico.

Comment: Nooooooooo I already have SQL procedure created properly and it even  WORKS(!) from mysql admin but I am trying to call it from PHP with dynamic IN variables and trying to read OUT but can't, too messy confused. Many thanks

Comment: Noooooooo calling works and query is made properly but unable to pass IN variables from PHP and read them out later

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you want to create a dynamic query string such as yours, you need to put {} around your variables in the string.

$query = "CALL my_procedure('{$inParam1}', '{$inParam2'}, '{$inParam3}', '{$inParam4}', '{$inParam5}', '{$inParam6}', '{$inParam7}', @outParam8, @outParam9, @outParam10); SELECT @outParam8, @outParam9, @outParam10;";

Comment: Noooooo that's not the problem and it won't work any way I have just provided how the code could look, but it's not working on any levels